# マクロで新しいファイルを生成できたときに、前の元のファイルではなく、新しくできたほうのファイルでマクロを続行させる方法

Tags: emeditor

画像のコードの並べ方では、生成の元になったほうのファイルで次のインクルードマクロが続行されます。
新しく生成したほうでマクロを続行させたいです。
画面はEmEditorです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご質問の意味がはっきりしないのですが、回答になっていなかったらご指摘ください。
`document` の対象を制御したいという意味でしょうか?
`document` プロパティ自体は、現在アクティブな文書になります。
`doc1 = document;` などとして、以前使った文書を保存しておくこともできます。
`doc1.Activate();` などとすると、以前使った文書をアクティブにして、その後の操作の対象となります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。次のような場合です。「まず最初に連番の元のファイルを選択する。→連番を全部結合して新しく結合ファイルが出来て自動的に開く。→マクロ処理をする」このようにするとマクロ処理自体が結合されて全部が生成されたファイルではなく、最初の001番のファイルに対してマクロが実行されます。これを連番を全部結合したほうの新しく生成されたファイルのほうでマクロを続行したいです。よろしくお願いいたします。